# JavaScript Multi-Select, move left right, option click not working after move

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem. I have two lists with multiple options. For a click event on any option in the list, the text contained inside the option is printed on the label. The problem is, when I perform a move (move an element to other list) the click event no longer works on that new element in the list.

I have added the code below. Your help is appreciated.

```
    <script>
        function moveAll(from, to){
            $('#'+from+' option').remove().appendTo('#'+to);}

        function moveSelected(from, to) {
            $('#'+from+' option:selected').remove().appendTo('#'+to);}
    </script>

<b style="margin: 10px;">Our List</b>

<select id="to" name="to[]" style="width:100px;" size="8" multiple="multiple">
</select>

<a href="javascript:moveAll('from', 'to')" class="controls">&lt;&lt;</a>
<a href="javascript:moveSelected('from', 'to')" class="controls">&lt;</a>
<a href="javascript:moveSelected('to', 'from')" class="controls">&gt;</a>
<a href="javascript:moveAll('to', 'from')" href="#" class="controls">&gt;&gt;</a>

<b style="margin: 10px;">Other List</b>

<select id="from" name="from[]" class="fromList" size="8" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Item1</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="x" disabled>Title</option>
</select>

<p id="Preview" class="Preview"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("option").on("click", function(){
        $('#QuestionPreview').html($(this).text());           
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned a click event handler on the newly created `option` elements. If you want to assign event handlers to elements that will appear in the future, you can assign the event handler to a parent that is already present (http://api.jquery.com/on).

In your case, this should work:

```
$('body').on('click', 'option', function() {
  $('#QuestionPreview').html($(this).text());           
});
```

I am using `body` for lack of a better option. Ideally, it should be the element that is a common parent to your `#from` and `#to` elements.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you mark the answer as done if it helped?